# Javascript works from browser address bar but not as a bookmark

Tags: javascript

I wrote the script below that clicks a data Save button and then clicks OK button when prompted to choose ok/cancel in a third party web app.

If I paste it to the browser address bar (I'm using FF) it works fine. From a FF bookmark, however, it does click both buttons but data change never gets saved.

I'd like to know why it behaves differently and how I can fix it so it works from the bookmark.

```
javascript:(function(){function%20d(){var%20b=setTimeout(d,500),e=document.querySelectorAll("div.m-flashMsg:nth-child(1)%20>%20div:nth-child(2)"),f=document.querySelectorAll("input.btnSet__item:nth-child(2)");1==a&&document.querySelector("div.btn--style02").click();1==e.length&&1<a&&0==c&&0==g&&(c=1,alert(e[0].innerHTML),document.querySelector(".modal__lnk%20>%20span:nth-child(1)").click(),clearTimeout(b));1==f.length&&6<a&&0==c&&(g=1,f[0].click(),clearTimeout(b));a+=1}var%20a=0,c=0,g=0,b=document.querySelectorAll("div.m-flashMsg:nth-child(1)%20>%20div:nth-child(1)");%201==b.length&&b[0].click();d()})();
```

Readable content:

```
(function(){
    function d() {
        var b=setTimeout(d,500),
        e=document.querySelectorAll("div.m-flashMsg:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)"),
        f=document.querySelectorAll("input.btnSet__item:nth-child(2)");
        1==a&&document.querySelector("div.btn--style02").click();
        1==e.length&&1<a&&0==c&&0==g&&(c=1,
            alert(e[0].innerHTML),
            document.querySelector(".modal__lnk > span:nth-child(1)").click(),
            clearTimeout(b))
        ;
        1==f.length&&6<a&&0==c&&(g=1,
            f[0].click(),
            clearTimeout(b)
        );
        a+=1
    }
    var a=0,c=0,g=0,
    b=document.querySelectorAll("div.m-flashMsg:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");
    1==b.length&&b[0].click();
    d()
})();
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to open console (F12?) or try to show the page you are working on. But suppose alert is not nice in bookmarklet and also not sure if timeout would work(?).

Comment: Maybe Tampermonkey can help in case you do not mind installing addOn... Example of a site script for my friend: https://openuserjs.org/scripts/eltomjan/KDD/source